How to identify an expletive / "dummy it" when sentence diagramming?
I found this diagram for the opening line of Pride and Prejudice:


It is a truth universally acknowledged, that a single man in possession of a good fortune must be in want of a wife.

If I'm understanding correctly, they've diagrammed "It" as an expletive or dummy pronoun.1 However, my initial thought was to diagram it like this as the subject:


I've seen other example sentences diagrammed with a detached word up top like this:2

There was a moon.


It is wrong to tell a lie.


The goose, have you killed him?

Here, there, it, and the goose are all diagrammed in basically the same way.
Moreover, I've seen it with names:

Alice, I went to the store.

This one is easy, because I understand that removing "Alice" from the sentence does nothing to change its meaning. It's clearly not modifying any other words. But the other examples are not so clear.

My question:
How can I reliably identify these expletives (or absolute elements, or interjections, or nouns of direct address, or whatever they are) when diagramming?
Presumably, this also entails figuring out exactly what they are in each case.

1 Or perhaps an absolute element?
2 These three examples come from Sentence Sense: A Diagramming and Parsing Handbook (2019), pp. 240–241. Notably, in the second example ("it is wrong..."), the author remarks "some grammars would classify it as a grammatical subject ... and treat to tell a lie as an appositive."
